# Div-Container sticky when it reaches left border of page, pushed out of sight by following containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I kinda search the whole internet for this, hopefully you guys can help me out.

I have a "stripe" of div-containers (images) side by side as a whole wider than the viewport so they force a horizontal scroll. After a certain amount of containers there should be "special containers" which - as they reach the left border of the viewport - stick to the left (so they are basically fixed). As scrolling continues, the next "special container" approaches, which pushes the first out of sight and takes its place, so it sticks to the left, too, and so on.

Basically I want to achieve something like this but horizontally:
http://jsfiddle.net/f3y9s/1/

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>-</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/projekt.css" title="nofilter">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
    <script src="js/waypoints-sticky.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function(){
            $(".post").wrapInner("<table><tr>");
            $("img").wrap("<td>");
            });

        $(function(){
            $("#projektimg").wrapInner("<table><tr>");
            $(".post").wrap("<td>");
            });
    </script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('.my-sticky-element').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $body.toggleClass(this.id + '-visible', direction === 'right');
}, {
  horizontal: true
});</script>-->

<script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-sticky-element').waypoint(function (direction) {
        if (direction=='right')
          $('.my-sticky-element').addClass('fixed');
        else {
           $('.my-sticky-element').removeClass('fixed');  
        }
    }, {
        horizontal: true

});
});</script>

</head>
<body>
        <div class="my-sticky-element"> 
            project description goes here
        </div>

<div id="projektimg">   
        <div class="post">
                <img src="img/1.jpg"/>      
                <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
                <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
                <img src="img/4.jpg"/>
                <img src="img/5.jpg"/>  
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
/* Global */

/* Reset */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline: 0;font-size: 100%;vertical-align: baseline;background: transparent;}body {line-height: 1;}ol, ul {list-style: none;}blockquote, q {quotes: none;}/* remember to define focus styles! */:focus {outline: 0;}/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */ins {text-decoration: none;}del {text-decoration: line-through;}/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */table {border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;}

* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border: none;
    }

body  {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    }

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #282828;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s;
    -moz-transition: color .2s;
    -o-transition: color .2s;
    -ms-transition: color 0,2s;
    transition: color .2s;
    }

a:hover {
    color: #ff8855;
    }

/* Projekt, Galerie */

#projektimg { 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    height: 510px;
    float: left;
    }                         

td  { 
    vertical-align: top; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    }

table, tbody { 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    }

tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

/* Sticky */

.my-sticky-element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    height: 440px;
    width: 210px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 5;
    }

.my-sticky-element.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    }
```

p.s.: I'm a bloody beginner with javascript.

Comment: do you have any screenshots?..so that I could imagine how really things would work..

Comment: I can provide you a gif animation:
http://juliusklaus.de/animation

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the jquery waypoints plugin:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#shortcuts-examples

Here is a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/UAGdf/7/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.container div:eq(1)').waypoint(function (direction) {
    //alert('here');
    if (direction=='right')
      $('.toggleme').addClass('fixed');
    else {
       $('.toggleme').removeClass('fixed');  
    }
}, {
    //offset: $.waypoints('viewportHeight') / 2,
    horizontal: true

});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2 <div class="toggleme">hmm</div></div>
    <div id="div3"><div class="toggleme">hmm</div></div>
    <div id="div4">div 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container>div {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;   
 }
.toggleme.fixed {position:fixed; left:0;top:0;z-index:100;background-color:blue}
.container {width: 5000px}
```

Please take note that you could just as easily do this with the div1,div2,div3 but that just depends on your implementation details.

Comment: It somehow won't work, seems like the script wouldn't run.. 
Also, if I add another toggleme-class div and run over the first one, it shows both: http://jsfiddle.net/UAGdf/5/ - Do I have to create a seperate class for every container?

Comment: What exactly are you tying to do?  If you want them stacked you need to change the top coordinate of one of them.  I've forked your example and have added some css to stack them as an example.  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/UAGdf/6/

Comment: I want, as soon as div 2 arrives at the left "hmm" sticks to it, same with div 3 and "ah". But "hmm" and "ah" stick simultaneously. I want "ah" to stick, when div 3 arrives the left border of the viewport. 

My second problem is, I can't get the script running.. Updated the code.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your current comment.  All the parts are there for you to put together for your specific implementation.

Comment: I built it now again from scratch, many things are still not working but at least the script does so I guess your job is done here, many thanks for helping!